# Access an object through a pointer in a field of another object C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have two classes declared like so:

(assume all other fields, methods, definitions, and includes are present and working properly)

```
class Child
{
    public:
        Child* parent;
        int value;

    //other fields and methods not listed
};
```

and

```
class Container : public Child
{
    public:
        void addChild(Child &);

    private:
        std::vector<Child *> children;

    //other fields and methods not listed
};
```

The addChild method:

```
void Container::addChild(Child &c)
{
    c.parent = this;
    children.push_back(&c);
}
```

When a Child object is added to the vector in a Container object, the address of the Container object is assigned to the parent field in the Child object.

In the following code

```
Container container;
Child child;

//value could be any number, for testing only.
container.value = 10;
//child is added to the container
container.addChild(child);

//Will print the same address
printf("%x, %x\n", &container, child.parent);

//This is where the problem occurs
printf("%d, %d\n", container.value, child.parent->value);
//10 should be printed both times
```

In the last statement, instead of 10 being printed twice, the first `%d` will print 10, but the second `%d` will print 0.

I do not know why this happens, and I am looking for a way for the Child object to store a pointer to its parent and retrieve the parent's fields without this problem occurring.

Comment: I think you need to use `new` operator and make object from child !

Comment: `Child* parent;` -> `Node* parent;` (naming)

Comment: There is no such thing as `child.parent->value`.  The last statement shouldn't even compile, much less present different values at runtime. `Child::parent` is simply a `Child*`, and `Child`, has no member `value` in the posted code.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think I meant to put the value field in the Child class, I edited the question.

Comment: @PatRoche Given the edit, and proper format specifiers for pointers, the posted code no longer behaves as you claim it does. [See example here](http://ideone.com/9RwN2t). The printed addresses are not equivalent (and they shouldn't be), and `10` is indeed printed twice (as it should be).

Comment: @WhozCraig _"The printed addresses are not equivalent"_ I think `&child.parent` was intended to be `child.parent`.

Comment: @Oktalist I'll fix that now

Comment: @Oktalist Well, then yeah, if that is the *real* code, I concur with you. I was just going by what the OP originally posted (silly me =P).

Comment: @Oktalist the real code had much more irrelevant stuff going on, I had to quickly write a simplified version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like WhozCraig said, `child.parent` is a `Child`. Move `value` to Child (as you already did in the update) and the code should output the expected values.